# Shared preferences with different context

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-context, android-sharedpreferences

What is the difference between these two:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application context);
```

and

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity context);
```

I am confused which one to use ?i want to make prefs static so that i can use it everywhere in my app.is it ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it shouldn't matter.

If you look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java#361) then you'll see that the context you pass in is used to create a name for your preferences. This is done by calling `context.getPackageName()`. So as long as both contexts return the same package name (and it should be the same for any context within your app) there is no difference between using those two.